# Material Angular 8 : Drawer content dissapears when there is no main content

Tags: angular-material

```
<mat-drawer-container class="fluid-container">
<mat-drawer mode="side" opened>

    <mat-form-field>
        <input (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" type="text" autofocus matInput placeholder="Enter the Area">
        <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear">
            <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </mat-form-field>

    <div>
        <label>Property For: </label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <mat-radio-group>
            <mat-radio-button [value]="buy">Buy</mat-radio-button> &nbsp;
            <mat-radio-button [value]="rent">Rent</mat-radio-button> &nbsp;
            <mat-radio-button [value]="bothFor">Both</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div>
        <label>Property Type: </label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <mat-radio-group formC>
            <mat-radio-button [value]="house">House</mat-radio-button> &nbsp;
            <mat-radio-button [value]="appartment">Appartment</mat-radio-button> &nbsp;
            <mat-radio-button [value]="bothType">Both</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
    </div>

    <div>
        <mat-form-field color="primary">
            <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="noOfBedrooms" (change)="bedroom_filter()" matInput placeholder="Bedrooms: " id="bedrooms">
            <mat-icon matSuffix>king_bed</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" matInput placeholder="bathrooms: ">
            <mat-icon matSuffix>bathtub</mat-icon>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" matInput placeholder="Min Amount:">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" matInput placeholder="Max Amount:">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div class="text text-center">
        <button mat-raised-button>Clear Filters</button>
    </div>


</mat-drawer>

<mat-drawer-content>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 offset-1 card" *ngFor="let data of filteredData">

            <div>
                &nbsp;
                <h3>{{data.price |currency :'INR'}}
                    <button mat-icon-button>
                        <mat-icon matSuffix aria-label="Heart">favorite</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div>&nbsp;For: {{data.propertyFor}}</div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <img class="img-fluid" src="../../assets/house.jpg" alt="House Image" />
            </div>

            <br>
            <table class="text text-center">
                <tr>
                    <td>1200 sq.Ft</td>
                    <td>2 BHK House</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fully Furnished</td>
                    <td>Reay to Move</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <br>
            <div class="text text-center">
                <button mat-stroked-button type="button">Contact Owner</button>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="text text-center">
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="sendProperty(data)">View Details</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</mat-drawer-content>
```

The above code is supposed to display filter data based on the values entered in the drawer content.
For now applyfilter() does nothing it is an empty function.Just prints("Hello") on the console.
bedroom_filter() filters data based on input in the input field with id = "bedrooms"
Whenever filteredData = [] the drawer content dissapears along with main content . How do i keep drawer content.
Works fine when filtered data is not empty.